# Animate the View with an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, imageview, jquery-animate

I have an ImageView, an ArrayList and a Button. My ArrayList has multiple numbers. For example 1,2,2,4,3. When i push the button, i want to animate the ImageView with the numbers inside ArrayList.
According to sample ArrayList. ArrayList[0]=1 ImageView will animate up, ArrayList[1]=2 ImageView will animate down. The animation will continue with all ArrayList inside. To do this, i have to use "for loop".
But the animation does not continue, the animation loop does not work. Only ArrayList[0] is working and then stop.`When i push the button second time, ArrayList[2] is working the stop. I have to push the button all the time for working all ArrayList. I want to push the button one time and i want to work all ArrayList.

```
//imageViewPlay=button     hareketler=ArrayList    imageViewMario=ImageView
    imageViewPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i=0;i<hareketler.size();i++){
                if (hareketler.get(0)==1){
                    imageViewMario.animate().y(imageViewMario.getY() -imageViewEngel.getHeight()-7).setDuration(2000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            hareketler.remove(0);
                        }
                    });

                }
                if (hareketler.get(0)==2){
                    imageViewMario.animate().y(imageViewMario.getY() +imageViewEngel.getHeight()+7).setDuration(2000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            hareketler.remove(0);
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (hareketler.get(0)==3){
                    imageViewMario.animate().x(imageViewMario.getX() +imageViewEngel.getHeight()+7).setDuration(2000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            hareketler.remove(0);
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (hareketler.get(0)==4){
                   imageViewMario.animate().x(imageViewMario.getX() -imageViewEngel.getHeight()-7).setDuration(2000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           hareketler.remove(0);
                       }
                   });
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

'Only ArrayList[0] is working and then stop' That is because you hardcoded this line with the value 0 :

```
if (hareketler.get(0)==...)
```

this will always only get the first item of your array.

You are incrementing your for loop, but not the positions that you are getting from the array.

```
if (hareketler.get(i)==...)
```

that will use the i value of the for loop to also increment the position of your array.

And then of course :

```
hareketler.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `withEndAction` is not a synchronous call and `for` did not wait for the first animation to end. What you need is recursive function which will be called again on animation end. Like this:

```
private void playAnimation(){
    if (hareketler.get(0)==1){
        imageViewMario.animate().y(imageViewMario.getY() -imageViewEngel.getHeight()-7).setDuration(2000).withEndAction(runnable);
    }else if .... and so on
```

Also create a runnable which will call the method again on animation end

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        hareketler.remove(0);
        playAnimation()
    }
};
```

And in your click listener:

```
imageViewPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playAnimation()
        }
    });
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: You are the Best. Thank You very much. It works

Comment: Thanks, If this is working then accept the answer